# Create jms queue on broker after first access

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, messaging, qpid

If want to create a qpid destination for a message publisher on spring integration jms. As an example I can create a queue like this:

```
<bean id="theTestQueue" class="org.apache.qpid.client.AMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg name="address" value="testQueue" />
    <property name="create" value="ALWAYS"/>
    <property name="node">
        <bean class="org.apache.qpid.client.messaging.address.Node">
            <constructor-arg name="name" value="testQueue"/>
            <property name="durable" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After that, I set this queue to the channel adapter:

```
<int:channel id="testChannel"/>
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="testChannel" destination="theTestQueue" session-transacted="true"/>
```

If the publisher sends the first message, the queue will be created on the message broker.

But what can I do, if I want to set queues dynamically?

```
<int:channel id="testChannel"/>   
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter destination-expression="headers.destination" channel="testChannel"/>
```

The publisher looks like:

```
@Publisher(channel = "testChannel")
public Message<?> sendMessage (Message<?> message, @Header("destination") String name) {
  return message;
```

}

The second param of the publisher-method is the name of the destination. That works if I create the queue on brokerside before I will send a message. My current solution is the creation by a jmx mbean before the publisher sends the first message. But I want to use jmx connections as few as possible. Is there a chance to create a queue automatically? Or maybe with an factory without jmx...

Thank you for help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may notice the `destination` attribute requires a `Destination` bean reference (`id`). From other side `destination-expression` can be evaluated to the `Destination` object as well.

If you have `org.apache.qpid.client.AMQQueue` bean definition for all those your "dynamic destinations", you just need to improve you expression to get appropriate bean from the application context

```
destination-expression="@beanFactoryAccessor.get(headers.destination)"
```

where `beanFactoryAccessor` is some simple bean which is injected with `BeanFactory` to invoke its `getBean()` by the provided `name`.

Comment: That is the problem, I have no definitions. My application executes different tasks. The tasks will be initiated over a GUI. The queues should be created depending on the id of the task. For example, if the taskID is `XYZ` the queue should be created and named as `testQueue.XYZ`. So I don't know, what for destinations are needed.

Comment: But maybe, I can create my own QueueFactory and put it to the destination-expression... i will try :)